# Is map in State object the same on all nodes?

Tags: java, apache-spark

This Spark App is running on 3 nodes. I have a State object(MessageState) that contains a HashMap. This HashMap contains a Graph(key leaf, value parent)(and no, GraphX is not a solution for this) Let's say the State object will become to big to fit on one node so it will be distributed on the other 2 nodes. If I want to know for a leaf it's most upper parent(it will do some recursive function to go through the whole map) is it a possibility that let's say that the leaf is on node 3 and the most upper parent is on node 1 and it will not find it or spark distribution will take care of that so the whole map data will be available for searching. My question in fact is how is the State distribution working.

```
JavaPairDStream<String, String> inputMessagesStream = readFromKafkaStream1();
   Function3<String, Optional<String>, State<MessageState>, String> messageState = (key, value, state) -> {
                //MessageState contains the HashMap
                if (state.exists()) {
                    return state.get().process(value.get());
                } else {
                    MessageState ms = new MessageState();
                    ms.process(value.get());
                    state.update(ms);
                    return null;
                }
            };

JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, String, MessageState, String> message1 = inputMessagesStream.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(messageState));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ["Return a JavaMapWithStateDStream by applying a function to every key-value element of this stream, while maintaining some state data **for each unique key**."](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html)

Since all values for a single key in a `PairRDDStream` are on a single node, the state for that key lives on the same node as well (if you have too many values, they can end up on several nodes, but Spark will still try to minimize amount of data it has to transfer). You can't access state for different keys from `mapWithState`, so "is it a possibility that let's say that the leaf is on node 3 and the most upper parent is on node 1 and it will not find it" doesn't apply.

Comment: Let's say we have the key = "firstKey". For this key, "firstKey", we will receive new values with every batch. Only for this key the value will be added to the HashMap that resides in this key State object. So in time, the hashmap will grow and at one point the state object that contains the hashmap will be to big to fit on one node so I presume that spark will 
distribute it on other nodes so isn't the question: "is it a possibility that let's say that the leaf is on node 3 and the most upper parent is on node 1 and it will not find it" valid?

Comment: And let the value be a markup Interface(not a string like in the example) and it can be 2 objects. One type that only adds data to the map and the other type that gets the parents from leafs. That's why I've been asking about state distribution. What will happen if the value if type of object that based on will search for parents but the leaf (starting point) is on another node.

Comment: Well, if you have `RDD<SomeLargeObject>`, do you expect to have each `SomeLargeObject` split between nodes, or for each node to have one or more complete `SomeLargeObject`?

Comment: I presume the SomeLargeObject is splitted if doesn't fit in memory? Well that's the problem, I don't know the distribution mode of spark State object and I'm also new to distributed systems and multiple jvms etc....

Comment: Ok. In that case, the answer is that it isn't split. And it really can't be: `MessageState` is your own type, Spark doesn't know anything about its internals. Any solution to split such classes between nodes would have to be reflection-based, slow and likely very limited.

Comment: So if your state for each key grows without bound, `mapWithState` is likely a wrong tool to use; instead, the state itself should be represented as an `RDD` or a `DStream`.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. Thank you for your help.